# 'Access is denied' while i am running a command in windows powershell

Tags: python, powershell, virtualenv

I am new to the `PowerShell` so this might be an easy question. I am trying to make a python 3.7 virtual environment using `virtualenv`. To give you some context in already have python 3.8 in my laptop what is added to the path variable but, python 3.7 is not added to the path variable while installation. the command I ran was

```
PS D:\Pranav\Software Output\Python> virtualenv --python="C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Python 3.7" p37\env1
RuntimeError: failed to query C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Python 3.7 with code 13 err: 'Access is denied'
PS D:\Pranav\Software Output\Python>
```

[image: 1]

Comment: Have u tried the command in a elevated terminal, by running as administrator ?

Comment: I think if you open powershell with administrator privileges, it will work for you. You can just do a right click on powershell app and you will find option to run as administrator.

Comment: it didn't work I tried it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason `python3 -m venv /path/to/new/virtual/environment` worked for me.
thank you for everyone who answered my question.

Answer (score 0):

I personally don't use power-shell as I am on Linux, but you can use the program as administrator when opening it, by right clicking on the application and then selecting run as administrator, for obvious reasons you will need administrator privileges or permission.

Comment: @Pranav Well, use the word `runas` before your command in the powershell, so your commands might look like `runas virtualenv --python="C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Python 3.7" p37\env1`